# Why is width from label in iOS ButtonRenderer alway 0?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to know the width of my title label in ButtonRenderer-Class in iOS, but it is always 0. There is text written and shown on the label, so it should not be 0.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(...){
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    { if(Control != null) {
      nfloat size = Control.TitleLabel.Frame.Size.Width;  //why always 0?}}}
```

Comment: It gives the same if I use var size

Comment: I would suppose it has not been really rendered yet and the Forms.ButtonWidth is still -1, so the native button width is 0 still at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you need to get it in the method **LayoutSubviews**  like following

```
using Foundation;
using System;


using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using CoreGraphics;
using App11.iOS;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Button),typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer:ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                                    
            }

        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();          
            nfloat size = Control.TitleLabel.Bounds.Width;

         }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if(e.PropertyName=="Width"|| e.PropertyName == "Height")
            {
                LayoutIfNeeded();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine when clicking on the page of the app the first time, but when changing to another page and coming back, it is shown false :(

Comment: You could save the value if the new value is 0 .

Comment: Where can I save it?

Comment: Set a property in the contentpage .

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue . If you have more question, you could create a new thread with more details so that I can help you better .